# CodeIgniter 4 Filter - exit with response

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have a project with CodeIgniter 4.

I have a `before` filter:

```
public function before(RequestInterface $request){

    $auth = $request->getHeader("Authorization");
    if($auth == null){

        $response = Services::response();
        $response->setStatusCode(401);
        $response->setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Bearer Token");
        $response->setBody("{\"error\": \"unauthorized\"}");

        exit;

    }

}
```

If there is no authorization, I want to stop the request and return `$response` to client.

Right now the request is stopped, because of `exit`.

But as answer I get `200 OK` and without `body content`.

How I can `exit` the request and set that `$response` to client?

Comment: What do you mean by setting `$response` to client? If you want to return an HTTP 401 with the header and the body you just set you simply need to add `return $response;` instead of `exit;`

Comment: Oh, I thought if I return something in `before`, it still execute the method from controller associated with path. But actually not. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, returning a Response object in the before method of a Filter prevent the execution of the controller. You don't need to use `die` or `exit`.

```
public function before(RequestInterface $request){

    $auth = $request->getHeader("Authorization");
    if($auth == null){

        $response = Services::response();
        $response->setStatusCode(401);
        $response->setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Bearer Token");
        $response->setBody("{\"error\": \"unauthorized\"}");

        return $response;

    }

}
```

Note that returning nothing with `return;` won't stop the controller from running.

Answer (score 3):

use **sendBody** method to print content of response.

```
public function before(RequestInterface $request){

    $auth = $request->getHeader("Authorization");
    if($auth == null){

        $response = Services::response();
        $response->setStatusCode(401);
        $response->setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Bearer Token");
        $response->setBody("{\"error\": \"unauthorized\"}");
        $response->sendBody();

        exit;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$response` is not available in before method:
So  I did the following in the before method to send the response and stop the execution :

```
      header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);
      die(json_encode(['error' => 'Unauthorized']));
```

Comment: `$response` is available through services in before method. @KunLun code is correct for this part.

Answer (score 0):

This is late but returning the response would prevent the execution of the controller.

I got a problem in the frontend from getting the `error.response` object of the axios response interceptor and solved it by adding the headers below.

```
$response = Service::response()
                   ->setContentType('application/json')
                   ->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http:://yourdomain.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I have experienced this filtering issue myself first hand. My situation was as follows (taken from `App\Config\Filters`):

`$globals` - CSRF and Filter A

Filter A returns in the same way as @ViLar proposes.

`$filters` - Filter B

Filter B was a generic filter and redirects if something fails.

The problem was that in my instance, I wanted Filter B to still run but as Filter A returns a response - Codeigniter stops processing. In fact I wanted Filter B really to take precedence over Filter A. Codeigniter compiles a list of filters to apply but picks up the *global* first followed then by the *filters* array.

My solution, (and I hope this helps anyone in a similar situation) was to edit the `System/Filters/Filters.php` (yes that is a core system file which some may not like) and the `initialize()` function and move `$this->processFilters($uri);` above the `$this->processGlobals($uri);` call.